What would happen to the sky colour if SO2 made up 95% of the atmosphere?
Because of the Rayleigh scattering phenomenon, I'm interested in how the G2V-type star light would interact with this composition, especially how it would change the colour of the sky. What kinds of changes could we see in the atmosphere if sulfur dioxide took over? Assume it is 1 bar. Would the sky be blue, or do you think it would be a completely new colour?

This question might be better asked on physics.SE or astronomy.SE

Already answered https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/164972/would-there-be-rayleigh-scattering-in-an-atmosphere-of-sulfur-dioxide
